# TFS 2010 - Deploy to Multiple Servers After Build

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I've configured TFS 2010 to do a build and utilizing the MSBuild arguments, have it deploying to a single server without any issues.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:Configuration=Development 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=http://<insert>/msdeployagentservice 
/p:username=<insert> 
/p:password=<insert>
```

However, I am now to the point where I'd like to deploy to multiple machines after a build.  I wasn't sure if there were some built in mechanisms for doing this, or should I invoke a process to launch a batch file that does this deployment followed by a sync?  I was hoping to keep things neat and tidy.

E.g., I could have two build definitions, one for each server, but that seems silly.  I was hoping to just build to both servers in one fail swoop without too many outside customizations.

Comment: Various answers for this issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519501/tfs2010-build-definition-to-deploy-to-multiple-servers/3544385#3544385

Answer (score 1):

As of TFS 2010 you can customize your build process using the build definition template, this is a much richer way of configuring your build process. Is there a specific reason why you're not using this?

Comment: Have you tried working with Workflow Foundation as of lately? In my experience, it's a rather rocky road.

Comment: It's different but to me it's much more visual as to what happens when I build a project

Comment: Yeah, been fooling around with it now this morning. I kinda like it... ;)