# TFS Build Workflow and MSBuild's output sequence

Tags: deployment, msbuild, msdeploy

I am modifying a copied build process template `BuildAndDeploy.xaml` to include a InvokeProcess activity. This activity would run the `_PublishedWebsites\ProjectName_Package\ProjectName.deploy.cmd` to deploy the web application to the QA server. Eventually I would run `ProjectName.deploy.cmd` multiple times for each of the servers in the web farm. Everything works fine manually but through the TFS build agent, the `_PublishedWebsites` folder and its contents are created too late. My first attempt was to add the `InvokeProcess` activity inside "`Compile the Project`" sequence as last step. Then I moved it after "`If Not DisableTests`". To troubleshoot I am running a dir /s command in the `BuildDetail.DropLocation` folder and it always outputs only logs folder and nothing else. I have also verified manually that the compiled output and the `_PublishedWebsites` folder and its contents are created after the point where I would like to run the `ProjectName.deploy.cmd` file. What location in the workflow would be ideal and guaranteed to have the `ProjectName.deploy.cmd` file and other related packaged content ready?

I am following approach given in accepted answer in [TFS2010 Build Definition to Deploy to multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519501/tfs2010-build-definition-to-deploy-to-multiple-servers/3544385#4315546).

The build drop location is a UNC path, if that matters. The parameters used in the MSBuild are `/p:DeployOnBuild=True`. The TFS Build creates the package properly and I can run the `ProjectName.deploy.cmd` and the web deploy runs smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BuildDetail.DropLocation\_PublishedWebsites` is created in activity `Revert Workspace and Copy Files to Drop Location` which is in the Finally of outer `Try Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items`. The appropriate location to look for this file would be `BinariesDirectory\_PublishedWebsites` instead of `BuildDetail.DropLocation\_PublishedWebsites`. That folder and all the files are created by MSBuild activity itself.